# Jquery slideshow works offline, but not online

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a website (www.saunahygiea.com) and I'm trying to use some javascripts but i'm new to it.

The background of the website should be a slideshow of some pictures. I therefore make use of a jquery. When i test it offline with dreamweaver everything looks fine and works great, but when i upload it online the background doesn't show the picture slidshow.

This is my html code for the script.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.backstretch.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.backstretch([
          "images/1.jpg",
          "images/2.jpg",
          "images/3.jpg",
          "images/4.jpg",
          "images/5.jpg",
          "images/6.jpg"
        ], {
            fade: 750,      //Speed of Fade
            duration: 4000  //Time of image display
        });
    </script>
```

The files jquery.js and jquery.backstretch.js are in the same directory as my website.

I downloaded the files from http://www.bluenotesentertainment.com/blog/full-size-background-slideshow/.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Images not found: http://www.saunahygiea.com/images/1.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Chrome Dev Console says:

```
GET http://www.saunahygiea.com/images/1.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

After checking your `/images` directory it turn's out that your images are there, but named like this

```
images/1.JPG
```

which means that the file extension is in uppercase. This seems to be case sensitive, so change your files to lowercase file extensions or adjust it to uppercase file extensions in your code.

Comment: Problem Solved! Thanks for the fast respond!